# Does the Ubuntu One mobile client have an integrated music store?

Tags: android, ubuntu-one

I was wondering if the Ubuntu One mobile client for Android has an integrated music store? I installed the client but I do not seem to be able to access the store.

Answer (score 5):

We don't have an "Ubuntu One mobile client for android", and the Ubuntu One Music client for android is only a client of the music streaming service, and nothing more. So, no, sorry. You currently need to use the Rhythmbox plugin or, in Natty, also the Banshee plugin.